# Regular Expression To Match Multiple Lines Of Text

Tags: regex, find-and-replace

I am trying to match lines that start with and end with the following tags using regular expressions:

```
<Description>
</Description>
```

Inbetween the tags, there can be multiple lines of text, how can I match this value? Example description tag:

```
<Description>
 test1
 test2
 test3
 test4
</Description>
```

I tried multiple variants of regular expressions which have not worked, here's the latest one I tried:

```
<Description>(\n.*)</Description>
```

EDIT: I am using Visual Studio 17s find/replace component when using regular expressions. Also, there are multiple instances of the description tags.

Comment: What tool are you using for regex? What do you want to replace with?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 17s find and replace component. Using a regular expression, I am trying to match and remove those description tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me in Visual Studio:

```
<Description>(\n|.)*?</Description>
```

It searches for end-of-line or any character, repeated, but not greedy (`?`).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<Description>([\s\S]*)</Description>
```

Comment: Thank you Reddy for the feedback, however, that has not worked.